# How to get one document using slug field from firebase (NextJs)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch only one document from firebase using the `getDoc` method, but I think it takes an `id` of the document, not the `slug` field of the document.

So, right now, I am fetching a document using the `getDocs` function, and I'm passing slug as a query so I only get one document from firestore:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const challenges = await getDocuments("challenges")

  const paths = challenges.map((doc) => {
    return {
      params: { slug: doc.slug },
    }
  })

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const slug = params.slug
  const data = await getDocuments("challenges", ["slug", "==", slug])
  const challenge = data[0]

  return {
    props: { challenge },
  }
}
```

getDocuments function

```js
export const getDocuments = async (c, q = null, l) => {
  const queryConstraints = []

  if (q !== null) queryConstraints.push(where(...q))
  if (l !== null) queryConstraints.push(limit(l))

  const ref = collection(db, c)
  const docsRef = query(ref, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"), ...queryConstraints)
  const documents = (await getDocs(docsRef)).docs.map(postToJSON)
  return documents
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there any better way to fetch a single document?
2. Will I get charged for a single document or all the documents that are in the "challenges" collection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there any better way to fetch a single document?

If you know the `doc id`, the better way is to use [`getdoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) as you mentioned.

Or if you are sure that, you have only one document which has value `slug == slug` you can try below snippet.

```
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./config/firebase.js";


const ref = collection(db, "challenges");
const q = query(ref, where("slug", "==", “slug”));
const snaps = (await getDocs(q)).docs;
Snaps[0]; // will return single document;
```

> 2. Will I get charged for a single document or all the documents that are in the "challenges" collection?

It will be charged per read, not for all documents. If you read one document, you will be charged for one document, not all. Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm already using the `getDocs` method in my code to fetch a single document by using this code `queryConstraints.push(where(...q))`. I don't know the id of the document so, I think using getDocs is the only way to fetch a document.